# Delete duplicate rows in mySQL in same table

Tags: mysql

I have this script running to check for duplicates in my table:

```sql
select s.id, t.* 
from [stuff] s
join (
   select name, city, count(*) as qty
   from [stuff]
   group by name, city
   having count(*) > 1
) t on s.name = t.name and s.city = t.city
```

This works fine and returns the ID's of the duplicate rows:

```py
myresult = cur.fetchall()
print(myresult)
```

Example output:

```
[(84,), (85,), (339,), (340,), (351,), (352,), (416,), (417,), (511,), (512,), (532,), (533,), 
(815,), (816,), (978,), (979,), (1075,), (1076,), (1385,), (1386,), (1512,)]
```

Now I want to delete records 84, 339, 351, 416, etc.
What would be the most convenient way to do so?

Comment: `DELETE FROM PRODUCTS WHERE ....`. You don't need Python at all. BTW in MySQL 8 and later it's easier and faster to use `ROW_NUMBER()`

Comment: Delete from products where ID = 84, 339, 351 etc. But how do I select the one of the two records? can I fetch this in my current sql statement somehow? I'm not an sql expert so it is a bit trial and error for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL provides you with the **DELETE JOIN** statement that allows you to remove duplicate rows quickly.

The following statement deletes duplicate rows and keeps the highest id:

```sql
DELETE t1 FROM table_name t1
INNER JOIN table_name t2 
WHERE 
    t1.id < t2.id AND 
    t1.unique_col = t2.unique_col;
```

In case you want to delete duplicate rows and keep the lowest id, you can use the following statement:

```sql
DELETE t1 FROM table_name t1
INNER JOIN table_name t2 
WHERE
    t1.id > t2.id AND 
    t1.unique_col = t2.unique_col;
```

Comment: So for me that would be:

DELETE t1 FROM stuff t1
INNER JOIN stuff t2
WHERE
 t1.id > t2.id AND
        t1.name = t2.name AND 
        t1.city = t2.city

Comment: yes, give a try and let me know if it not works

Comment: Ok, I will try with a SELECT first ;-) Just to be sure
SELECT t1 FROM stuff t1 INNER JOIN stuff t2 WHERE t1.id > t2.id AND t1.name = t2.name AND t1.city = t2.city

Comment: Glad to know that. Please give an upvote

Answer (score 0):

you can remove duplicate rows in MySQL in this way

```
      WHERE customer_id NOT IN
      (
          SELECT
          customer_id
          FROM
          (
              SELECT MIN(customer_id) as customer_id
              FROM CUSTOMERS
              GROUP BY CONCAT(first_name, last_name, phone)
          ) AS duplicate_customer_ids
      );`
```

Comment: may use MAX or MIN function depends of your requirement

Comment: other thing...the above example is in the case of all of your records are duplicated. But, if there are somes uniques records, you neeed include other sql query with UNION statement. This for not delete this uniques records. Algo como ..

 ```SQL 
WHERE customer_id NOT IN
..
          UNION
       SELECT
          customer_id
          FROM
          (
              SELECT MIN(customer_id) as customer_id
              FROM CUSTOMERS
              GROUP BY CONCAT(first_name, last_name, phone)
              having count(*) = 1
          ) AS duplicate_customer_ids
    )